# how to display button when menu button is pressed in android

Tags: android, menu

hi friends i want to pop up a button from the bottom of my screen when the default menu button is pressed on the android key pad. i want to navigate from that pop button to other screens.

Comment: http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-an-option-menu,427.html

Comment: other method is to use onKeyDown event http://progrnotes.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-menu-button-click-event.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to declare your desired menu in /menu/menu.xml
then you need a inflater for your menu:

```
// menuinflater 
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And to handle your menu:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // only one menu option here for preferences
        // for more just add new case with your ids
        case R.id.firstmenuitem:
            // Launch preferences activity
            Intent i = new Intent(youractivity.this, preferences.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }
```

regards